# How do I use multiple parameters in a messaging extension?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a messaging extension which makes use of two parameters in Teams.

I have created a messaging extension which takes two parameters in the manifest. After this, I have made a bot server using the botbuilder-teams v4.0.0-beta1 package in node.

The manifest contains the following:

```
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "########-####-####-####-############",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "Test",
                    "title": "Test",
                    "description": "test",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "Param1",
                            "title": "Param 1",
                            "description": "This is param 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Param2",
                            "title": "param 2",
                            "description": "param 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

And I have the below code in my server to reply to messaging extension requests

```
private onMessagingExtensionQuery = async (ctx: TurnContext, query: teams.MessagingExtensionQuery): Promise<teams.InvokeResponseTyped<teams.MessagingExtensionResponse>> => {
    console.log(query);
    type R = teams.InvokeResponseTypeOf<'onMessagingExtensionQuery'>;
    let heroCard1 = CardFactory.heroCard('Result Card1', '<pre>This card mocks the CE results 1</pre>');
    let heroCard2 = CardFactory.heroCard('Result Card2', '<pre>This card mocks the CE results 2</pre>');
    let response: R = {
      status: 200,
      body: {
        composeExtension: {
          type: 'result',
          attachmentLayout: 'list',
          attachments: [
            {...heroCard1},
            {...heroCard2}
          ]
        }
      }
    };
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  };
```

When I attempt to use my messaging extension, I enter the first paramater and the two result cards are shown and I can select one. However, after this I have no option to enter a second parameter. Instead, I just have the selected card in my chat box ready to send to my bot.

How do I make use of both of these messaging extension parameters?

Thanks

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thanks for the reply, I'd mark it as an accepted answer if you would write it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-parameter is only supported for command type set to action. For query we only support 1 parameter currently. The way it surfaces in the UI is with a simple form in the task module.